# comparison array doesnt work

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code which I'm trying to compare  $current to $password which is array and even thought both have same value and doesn't work.

```
$current_password = mysqli_query($db_connection,"SELECT password FROM
                                     user WHERE username  = 'sanket' ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($current_password);
foreach($row as $pass)
{
    $password = $pass[0];
}
$current = $_POST['old_password'];
if ($current == $password) {

    if ($_POST['new_password'] == $_POST['confirm_password']) {

    mysqli_query($db_connection,"UPDATE user SET password
    = ".$_POST['confirm_password']."   WHERE username  = 'sanket'") ;

}
```

Comment: Why would the password (either of them) be an array? Also, http://bobby-tables.com/ You're already working with mysqli, use the positional parameters.

Comment: when you meet this kind of problems, just var_dump these variables and check whether they are equal, and then you can easily find the problem.

Comment: well i did var dump and $current and $password match in array but it doesnt go further then comparing between two variables

Answer (score 2):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($current_password);
foreach($row as $pass)
{
    $password = $pass[0];
}
```

`$row` is already an unidimensional array with strings. When you foreach over `$row` then `$pass` will be a string. So when you then assign `$pass[0]` to `$password`, you assign the first character of the string in `$pass` to `$password`. So just write:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($current_password);
$password = $row[0];
```

---

And here the necessary warning: Use proper escaping with `mysqli_prepare` or `mysqli_real_escape_string` for user input!

Comment: still doesnt work basically $_POST['old_password'] is single dimentional array and $row['password'] is two or multi dimention array and baically everything works except comparring between these two varables

Comment: I swear, `$row` is unidimensional. (this is what mysqli_fetch_array returns)